# How to convert JWK to PEM format in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, openssl, pem, delphi-10.2-tokyo, jwk

I have this RSA public key in JWK format:

```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "kid": "55c188a83546fc188e51576ba72836e0600e8b73",
  "n": "q0CrF3x3aYsjr0YOLMOAhEGMvyFp6o4RqyEdUrnTDYkhZbcud-fJEQafCTnjS9QHN1IjpuK6gpx5i3-Z63vRjs5EQX7lP1jG8Qg-CnBdTTLw4uJi7RmmlKPsYaO1DbNkFO2uEN62sOOzmJCh1od3CZXI1UYH5cvZ_sLJaN2A4TwvUTU3aXlXbUNJz_Hy3l0q1Jjta75NrJtJ7Pfj9tVXs8qXp15tZXrnbaM-AI0puswt35VsQbmLwUovFFGeToo5q2c_c1xYnV5uQYMadANekGPRFPM9JZpSSIvH0Lv_f15V2zRqmIgX7a3RcmTnr3-w3QNQTogdy-MogxPUdRbxow"
}
```

I need to convert it to PEM format. This [website](https://keytool.online) does the conversion, but I need to do it in Delphi. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66520594/how-to-convert-json-web-key-to-pem-format-in-delphi) SO post that asks the same question but the answer provided does not work with my data because the "d", "x" and "y" JSON keys are missing in my input data (meaning my data is a different format).

In that same SO post, Arnaud Bouchez suggested using code from the Mormot2 library to do the work, and I've downloaded that library from GitHub but I can't seem to figure out how to start using it for this scenario.

I have also had a look and installed ["Delphi JOSE and JWT Library"](https://github.com/paolo-rossi/delphi-jose-jwt) but cannot figure out how to write the code to do what I need. I believe that this library may be able to do what I need.